# Ionic open page with animation

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to open page from right to left with animation in Ionic, to be like slide

i have tried like with this got no luck, it got from down to up?

```
this.navCtrl.push(HomePage, {}, { animate: true, direction: 'forward' });
```

Comment: Did you try `direction:'back'`?

Comment: Then goes from up to down :)

Comment: This looks somewhere close to your issue. Check it out if not. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7459

Comment: I believe Android goes from bottom to top but if you put `"animation": "ios-transition"` in the NavOptions then it should use the iOS animation which is from right to left. See [the docs.](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) for reference.